# Wrap angular directive with different model datatype

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

Before I issue my actual question, some background info about what I wanna do.

angular-material's mdDatepicker directive offers a nice GUI to select a date. As a model, however, the directive needs a date object. This causes lots of issues concerning time zone, JSON serialization etc. So my idea was to create some kind of wrapper directive which takes a string as a model, converts it to a date und hands it over to the mdDatepicker directive. Same in reverse, of course: if the user picks a date in the mdDatepicker, it is serialized to a string and then handed back to the model assigned to the wrapper directive.

The way from the model to the directive works, but the watch back from the directive to the model just doesn't fire.

Here's my directive:

```
app.directive("stringDatepicker", function($compile) {

  this.template = '<md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.date" md-placeholder="{{placeholder}}"></md-datepicker>';

  return {    
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'stringDatepicker',

    scope: {
      placeholder: '@mdPlaceholder',
      dateString: "=dateString"
    },
    controller: StringDatepickerCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  template: template,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

    var StringDatepickerCtrl = controller;

    StringDatepickerCtrl.attachChangeListeners();
  }

  };

});
```

This is my directive's controller:

```
function StringDatepickerCtrl($scope)
{

  /** @final {!angular.Scope} */
  this.$scope = $scope;

  /** @type {Date} */
  this.date = null;

  /** @type {string} */
  this.dateString = null;

};
StringDatepickerCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];

StringDatepickerCtrl.prototype.attachChangeListeners = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.$scope.$watch('dateString', function(event, value) {    
    var dateParts = value.split('-');

    if (dateParts.length < 3)
    {
      self.dateString = "";
      self.date = null;
      throw Error("The ng-model value of <string-datepicker> directive must be a valid date string in the format YYYY-MM-dd, i.e. 2015-12-14 for 14th December 2015." + 
    "You provided " + value + " as input.");
    } 
    self.date = new Date(dateParts[0], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[2]);
  });

  self.$scope.$watch('date', function(event, value) {
    self.dateString = value.getFullYear() + "-" + (value.getMonth()+1) + "-" + value.getDate();
  });

};
```

Here's a fiddle you can play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/t5vyync9/3/

Any ideas why the watch on 'date' doesn't work? Or maybe you guys have a much better idea how to tackle my problem?

Thank you very much!